# PHP Selinux exec / permission denied

Tags: php, selinux, fedora

In Fedora how do you configure Selinux to give permissions to an arbitrary executable to be run by the PHP system or exec functions? Turning SELinux off is not an option for me.

```
$ getsebool -a | grep httpd  

allow_httpd_anon_write --> off  
allow_httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off  
allow_httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off  
allow_httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off  
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on  
httpd_can_check_spam --> off  
httpd_can_network_connect --> off  
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off  
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off  
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off  
httpd_can_network_relay --> off  
httpd_can_sendmail --> off  
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off  
httpd_enable_cgi --> on  
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off  
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off  
httpd_execmem --> off  
httpd_read_user_content --> off  
httpd_setrlimit --> off  
httpd_ssi_exec --> on  
httpd_tmp_exec --> off  
httpd_tty_comm --> on  
httpd_unified --> off  
httpd_use_cifs --> off  
httpd_use_gpg --> off  
httpd_use_nfs --> off
```

Comment: Please run the request again an provide the log results of "ausearch -ts recent -m avc"

Answer (score 6):

Check the current SELinux settings related to Apache with:

```
# /usr/sbin/getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

You need to turn on `httpd_ssi_exec` to allow Apache to execute SSI scripts:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_ssi_exec=1
```

Comment: I already tried it. In the httpd log it still shows "permission denied".

Comment: Please post a log snippet?

Comment: sh: /tmp/defne/eq7ZO4fu8lYI: Permission denied

This is the only relevant thing in /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: What did you try? Edit your original post to append the `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: IT SAYS: "End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak:" but apparently it is not working, I hope you can read this:



# cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep executableFileName  

type=AVC msg=audit(1320562016.878:1786): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=6004 comm="sh" name="executableFileName" dev=dm-1 ino=536509 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file

Comment: What does `executableFileName` look like? What are you trying to do with `/tmp/defne/eq7ZO4fu8lYI`? How can we help if you keep supplying so little information?

Comment: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01

Answer (score 3):

Just bumped into this same issue. Setting `httpd_execmem` to on solved the problem.